# How to run left outer join SQL query in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am unable to write this query in laravel using query builder:

````
```
SELECT pt.name, IF(up.permission_id IS NULL,'false','true') permission
    FROM mercuri_permission_type pt 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mercuri_user_permission up 
    ON pt.id = up.permission_id AND up.user_id = $user_id
```
````

Comment: .... and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should do multi `left join` to handle this; But I suggest you use doctrine ORM and run this query on doctrine. In order to use Doctrine in Laravel the links below would be useful:

[Getting started doctrine 2 laravel](http://culttt.com/2014/06/30/getting-started-doctrine-2-laravel/)

[Working entities doctrine 2](http://culttt.com/2014/07/14/working-entities-doctrine-2/)

[Creating testing doctrine repositories](http://culttt.com/2014/10/13/creating-testing-doctrine-repositories/)

[Using doctrine query language](http://culttt.com/2014/07/28/using-doctrine-query-language/)